# replace up to nth match

Tags: bash, sed

With `sed` I [**read**](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-8) that you can replace all matches starting with the second

> You can combine a number with the g (global) flag. For instance, if you want to 
>   leave the first word alone, but change the second, third, etc. to be DELETED 
>   instead, use /2g:

example

```
sed 's/foo/bar/2g' a.txt
```

However how could you replace matches **up to** the second, so that the third, fourth, etc are not affected? Something like

```
sed 's/foo/bar/1-2' a.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/foo/&\n/2;T;h;s//bar/g;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Replace the nth occurence of the intended string by itself and a newline.
If the substitution fails bail out else copy the pattern space (PS) to the hold space (HS).
Make the substitution using the replacement string and then reconstitute the original line with the altered line.

Also:

```
sed 's/foo/\n/g;s/\n/foo/3g;s/\n/bar/g' file
```

Where nth +1 is used instead of the 1 to the nth

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is:

```
sed 's/foo/bar; s/foo/bar' a.txt
```

This will make effectively replace the 2 first occurrences of `foo`. It makes two passes per line, replacing always the first occurrence. Since on the second pass the first `foo` has already been replaced, the second pass 'sees' the original second occurrence as the first.

Answer (score 0):

extending Chirlo's answer...

```
replace_string=s/foo/bar
n=2
replace_string_n=`python -c 'print "'$replace_string';"*'$n`

sed $replace_string_n a.txt
```