# use sed to remove first Nth and last Nth characters from string only if matching X

Tags: regex, linux, string, bash, sed

I would like to use `sed` to remove the first Nth occurrences and the last Nth occurrences of a specific symbol in each string. For example, I would like to remove the first and last square brackets from the string below. The number of nested brackets is unknown, it could be

> [{string[substring]string}]

or

> [[[{string[substring]string}]]]

after sed should leave

> {string[substring]string}

I tried following the logic of [replace up to nth match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043789/replace-up-to-nth-match)
and [How to remove the last character from all lines but only if it is a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606995/how-to-remove-the-last-character-from-all-lines-but-only-if-it-is-a-certain-char) but could not find a formula that worked for an unknow amount of nested brackets.

Worst case I could recursively test the string to get the number of nested brackets, then remove that number of characters. Would that be a better method and what would the formula look like? I tried `sed -r 's/.{2}//' -e 's/ .{2}$//'` with no luck

Thx
Art

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to count brackets, you just need to use proper pattern. You can do it like this:

```
sed "s/^\[*{/{/;s/}\]*$/}/"
```

there are two patterns here for replace, s means replace what is before `/` to what is after:

```
s/^\[*{/{/
```

This one will seek for `{` with any amount of `[` starting from the beginning of the string. `^` - means beginning of the string, `*` means anything, using `\` we escaping `[`. So we replacing here `^\[*{` with just `{`.

```
s/}\]*$/}/
```

Vise versa situation is here, but we seek for `}` with any amount of `]` till the end of the string. `$` means end. And we replacing here `}\]*$` with just `}`.

Comment: thanks @SandyElms worked a charm. Could you explain what is going on in that formula. I get [* & \]* sets the wild card Nth number, but what does the {/{/ do?